# consumer plastics that can take a bit of heat

Tags: materials

I'm throwing a party with themed drinks, and one is a shot topped with 151, and set on fire.

I'll need to serve about 15 at a time, and don't own that many shot glasses.

Is there any disposable drinking glass that can be safely held at ~130 f (the only actual number I found online, but probably not too precise) for less than a minute?  What plastic number (the recycling number) should I look for?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and go to a "dollar store" and buy glass shot glasses.(If you live in the US). Otherwise, sounds like fun

Comment: Alcohol burns at what temperature?

Comment: this is an engineering question how?

Comment: Where would you migrate it to, @agentp? Until there is a Materials Science StackExchange, Engineering isn't such a bad choice.

Answer (score 3):

There are plastics out there which can deal with high temperatures, but they certainly won't present a more cost-effective solution than glass in this instance.

[image: (c) Copyright Granta Design Ltd, Cambridge, England www.grantadesign.com]